# ¿ Por qué se me crashea la app?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando poner 2 bases de datos a la vez en mi aplicación y no sé por qué, ¿ qué estoy haciendo mal ? Pongo mis dos bases de datos y los cambios que he usado para referirme a una y a otra ( cambios variables y demás) :

La que sí funciona :

`public class BaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

```
String tabla ="CREATE TABLE Notas(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Primero INTEGER, Segundo INTEGER)";

public BaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(tabla);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

`}`

// Como lo llamo :

`public void cargar () {`

```
        BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if(db!=null){

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notas ORDER BY Primero DESC LIMIT 5",null);
            final int cantidad = c.getCount();
            int i=0;
            String[] arreglo = new String [cantidad];


            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do{

                    String linea = c.getInt(0)+"                   "+ c.getInt(1)+" Clicks";

                    arreglo[i] = linea;

                    i++;
                }while(c.moveToNext());

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arreglo);
            ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

La que no funciona :

`public class BaseHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

```
String tabla2 ="CREATE TABLE Notas2(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Primero INTEGER, Segundo INTEGER)";

public BaseHelper2(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db2) {

    db2.execSQL(tabla2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db2, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

// Como la llamo:

`public void cargar () {`

```
        BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db2 = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if(db2!=null){

            Cursor c2 = db2.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notas2 ORDER BY Primero DESC LIMIT 5",null);
            final int cantidad2 = c2.getCount();
            int i=0;
            String[] arreglo2 = new String [cantidad2];


            if(c2.moveToFirst()){
                do{

                    String linea2 = c2.getInt(0)+"                   "+ c2.getInt(1)+" Clicks";

                    arreglo2[i] = linea2;

                    i++;
                }while(c2.moveToNext());

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arreglo2);
            ListView lista2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            lista2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

He intentado cambiar variables , eso es posible? ¿ Es posible que sea por el nombre al ponerle un "2" ya que debe llamarse si o si "BaseHelper" ?

Comment: Por cierto, debieras repasar tus apuntes de programación orientada a objetos. Lo que estás haciendo quizás debiera ir en un método aparte... pero crear una clase exactamente igual, es raro.
Cuando tengas eso dominado, dale un vistazo a algunos patrones de diseño que también te podrían ser útiles.

Comment: No, ya está, sí que me dejaba, no me ha hecho falta repasar ningun apunte :) . Simplemente me faltaba un "2" y ya está, salu2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, en tu segundo código, para el método cargar, debieras dejar:

```
BaseHelper2 baseHelper = new BaseHelper2 (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
```

Comment: Si, lo puse despues, me di cuenta 1 minuto despues de ponerlo aqui, gracias! Ahora tengo un problema con el código, si persigue lo pondré aquí porque de nuevo llevo con esto ya mucho tiempo